# Find files/folders that are modified after a specific date in Python

Tags: python, file-io

Problem ; find files/folders that are changed after a specific date from a directory structure and copy these to another location (as stated clearly in title as well) (:

By the following ;

```
def mod():
     """Find files modified today, given a file path."""
     latest = 0
     now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime())
     dir = "/home/y33t/"
     for fname in os.listdir(dir):
         if fname.endswith(''):
             modtime = os.stat(os.path.join(dir, fname)).st_mtime
             if modtime > latest:
                 latest = modtime
                 out = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(latest))
                 if out == now:
                     print fname, "has changed today. "
                 else:
                     pass
```

I can determine which files are changed at a specific date and copy these to a location. What I would like to achieve is to keep the directory structure as well. An example is as following ;

```
/testfolder
..somefile1
..somefile2
../testfolder2
....somefile3
....somefile4
```

and so on...

lets say somefile3 is changed at the specified date and I will save it to another location but while saving, cascaded directory structure should be maintained as well. How can I achieve this in an elegant way ?

Answer (score 1):

Before copying, you should solve reading. `os.listdir` will give you only one level while `os.walk` will let you go over each file in every depth.

To copy, you will first use `os.makedirs(target-path)` to create all the folders from root to target folder at any depth then you will use `shutil.copy` to copy the file.

Comment: did you try the code I provided and checked out the outcome ?

Comment: I did not create a folder structure and tried your code :) However I know exactly what it does. It takes the list of files only in your base folder (/home/y33t/) not the files/folders in deeper levels like somefile3 and somefile4. Its second mistake is that it takes everything on the returned list as a file. testfolder2 there shouldn't be checked for mtime; but browsed. You could do this by recursively calling os.listdir by making base folder as a parameter instead of a fixed function-scope variable. However, os.walk makes more sense to me for this kind of recusive *walks* :)